# can a html file inside apk be accessed by external apk

Tags: android

Is it possible to call or access HTML file which exists in another apk ?

example:

```
lets assume one.apk has index.html in its assest folder

is it possible to access the index.html in another web view ?
```

or is there any workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On current android devices, .apk files (at least those under /data and /system) are world readable.  The /data directory is not listable, so you need the full and specific path of an apk to access it.  Currently this can be found in /data/system/packages.xml

If you want to access it with a web view, you will probably first have to track it down and extract your own copy from the apk, by treating it as a zip file, then point your webview at that.

Of course this is not official functionality - it could go away, so best not to rely on it.  The more important point is you must not rely on someone not doing this to your apk, because they actually can.

Comment: Of course.  But its important to know the reality, at least of what someone else can do to your apk.

Comment: Thanks a lot chris i am just figuring out different methods for automating testing in a web view.

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not possible. Its private to only that .apk. So in other .apk file you can't. Its all about Android Application Security concern.

Or something for try,  (I am not sure this one help you or not) The [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) object gives you access to assets. [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) can give you access to the `Resources` for an application.

Comment: Incorrect. The actual .apk files are generally accessable.  Files in private storage - which may include extracted copies of apk contents - are generally not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I Think he can access using PackageManager.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No Never..

The security architecture of the Android will not allow one application to access resources of another application.

Every application is treated as different users. Can a user access the personal files of another user in your desktop machine when protected?? Same goes here.

Comment: so say i have an index.html in my external-sd can i then access it in my webview ?

Comment: Incorrect. The actual .apk files are generally accessable.  Files in private storage - which may include extracted copies of apk contents - are generally not.

Comment: You can definitly access the index.html file in your sd card. There is no restriction when accesing files on SD-CARD.